# Change the default shape of UIImageview shape rectangle

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiimageview

Now I m developing an project in that I need to show the image with border like below shape.

[image]

How can I do this? I have no idea to do this. Please any idea to solve.

Comment: Is it a static image or a kind of control and you need to process touch events when user touches the image? Do you create the image in an image editor or you need to create image programmatically?

Comment: @yurish:static image..The user image download from internet.. Then show the image in above step

Comment: I accepted the below answer but it wont give the exact shape I mentioned above...

Comment: @user2922837 ok no prob bro...

Comment: To build the shape you need use `[UIBezierPath bezierPath]` to create the maskPath then add each shape segment with `addLineToPoint:`... `addArcWithCenter:` ... `closePath:` methods of UIBezierPath class.

Comment: @yurish:Please post some of the code as you said..

Answer (score 10):

May be this code will help you...

```
 UIBezierPath *maskPath;
 maskPath = [UIBezierPath bezierPathWithRoundedRect:YourImageVIew.bounds byRoundingCorners:(UIRectCornerTopRight | UIRectCornerBottomRight) cornerRadii:CGSizeMake(50.0, 50.0)];

 CAShapeLayer *maskLayer = [[CAShapeLayer alloc] init];
 maskLayer.frame = YourImageVIew.bounds;
 maskLayer.path = maskPath.CGPath;
 YourImageVIew.layer.mask = maskLayer;
```

Comment: :can you please tell about imgtest?

Comment: oh sorry that is your original image

Comment: @user2922837 now check my updated answer... i check this code in my application and it's work for me.

Comment: From your method i didn't goe exact shape I want

Comment: @user2922837 change the cornerRadii value as per your requirement

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/42104/discussion-between-pradhyuman-chavda-and-user2922837)

Comment: @I give full radious 100 but I didn't get that shape.

Answer (score 1):

Here is how you can create the path for masking:

```
- (UIBezierPath *)curvedRectWithFrame:(CGRect)frame radius:(CGFloat)radius
{
    double halfFrameHeight = ((double)frame.size.height / 2);

    // Check if the radius is too small.
    if (radius < halfFrameHeight) {
        radius = halfFrameHeight;
    }

    CGFloat arcAngle = asin(halfFrameHeight/radius);
    CGFloat centerX = frame.origin.x + (frame.size.width - radius);
    CGFloat centerY = frame.origin.y + halfFrameHeight;

    UIBezierPath *path = [UIBezierPath bezierPath];

    [path moveToPoint:frame.origin];
    [path addLineToPoint:CGPointMake(centerX + radius * cos(arcAngle), frame.origin.y)];
    [path addArcWithCenter:CGPointMake(centerX, centerY) radius:radius startAngle:-arcAngle endAngle:arcAngle clockwise:YES];
    [path addLineToPoint:CGPointMake(frame.origin.x, path.currentPoint.y)];
    [path closePath];

    return path;
}
```

Then you can apply the shape mask to your image:

```
const CGFloat kCurveRadius = 500.;

CAShapeLayer *maskLayer = [[CAShapeLayer alloc] init];
maskLayer.frame = yourImageView.bounds;
maskLayer.path = [self curvedRectWithFrame:maskLayer.bounds radius:kCurveRadius].CGPath;

yourImageView.layer.mask = maskLayer;
```